# Connecting two containers MongoDB + Python project

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, pymongo

I'm trying to connect two containers, one of them is using pymongo and I want to connect from inside one container, to the second, I am able to connect to it from the machine I'm running the docker on, but I can't connect from one container to another, I've tried every solution possible, but I'm sure I'm missing something:

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
networks:
  shared:
    driver: bridge

services:
  application:
    environment:
      ....
    image: application:latest
    ports:
      ....
    volumes:
      ....
    depends_on:
        - mongo
    networks:
      - shared
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2-bionic
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
    networks:
    - shared
```

connection:

```
def get_connection():
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    database = client.database.beacons
    return database
```

error:

```
Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 621d188d8169b99b9cfc4c5e, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Containers in a docker-compose network are referenced by their service name, so in your pymongo connection use:

```
client = MongoClient('mongo', 27017)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue,
While my Python app container used a simple Dockerfile,
The MongoDB image was taken from the Docker images.
Renaming the host, in the client creation line, to the name of the MongoDB container, did the job.

creating containers:

```
docker run -d --network statusmapnet -p 27017:27017 --name statusmap-mongodb mongo

docker run -d --network statusmapnet -p 5000:5000 --name statusmap statusmap-flask
```

server.py:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient('statusmap-mongodb', 27017)
```